# Best way to understand how to write out code

Tags: javascript, loops, object, for-in-loop

I am currently in a accelerated codeing program and I am having trouble writing out code. Or more so, deciphering a question that asks me to write out code.

for example:  * Given an input Object, loop over the Object and print its values using console.log().

what I deciphered is it wants me to do a for loop but its an object so I need to use a for in loop.

here's what I've done so far:

```
function printObjectValues(object) {
var object = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
};
for (var key in object) {
  console.log(object[key])
}
```

In checking it says I'm still wrong. "An assertion error: expected false to be true."

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is working for me, though you aren't using the object passed to the function

Comment: You are given an input of `object` see `printObjectValues(object)` but you immediately overwrite the variable see `var object = {`. Also, when you are doing `for in` add a `hasOwnProperty` check

Comment: Try removing the `var object`

Answer (score 0):

`object` should be outside of the function, otherwise, there's no point in using a function. The code you have provided is working correctly. It is logging the values of all elements in the object:

```js
var object = {
  one: "first",
  two: "second",
  three: "third",
};

function printObjectValues(object) {

  for (var key in object) {
    console.log(`${key} => ${object[key]}`)
  }
}

printObjectValues(object)
```